# update query issue using jsp

Tags: database, jsp, sql-update, resultset

Please resolve update query (using jsp)

//resultset is ResultSet object & working properly
//rsmd is ResultSetMetaData object & fetching data properly

```
    for(int i=1;resultset.next();i++)
    {
    update_query="UPDATE DEMO_TABLE SET ";

    for(int j=1;j<=rsmd.getColumnCount();j++)
    {
        temp_str=request.getParameter(rsmd.getColumnName(j)+i);     // i am having id of textboxes as of columnname1,columnname2(eg. S_NO1, NAME1) using this

        if(j==rsmd.getColumnCount())
        {
           update_query+=rsmd.getColumnName(j)+"=\'"+temp_str+"\'" ;//not working
//WORKING  update_query+=rsmd.getColumnName(j)+"=\""+ temp_str+"\""  ;
        }

        else
        {
           update_query+=rsmd.getColumnName(j)+ "=\'"+ temp_str+"\' ,";//not working
//WORKING  update_query+=rsmd.getColumnName(j)+ "=\"" + temp_str + "\" ,";
        }
    }

.
.
.
.
remaining update query statement with where clause...

please help...it's not working i.e. it's not inserting single quotes in update_query string
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems no problem with syntax, should work.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String strColName="empName";
        String strVal = "smith";
        String update_query = "Update employee SET "; 
        update_query += strColName + "=\'"+ strVal +"\'"; 
        System.out.println(update_query);
    }
```

Output:

> run:
>
> Update employee SET empName='smith'
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)